# Does spring-data-solr have a way to provide json.facet parameter?

Tags: spring-data-solr

As far as I can tell there is not a way to provide a facet.json to using spring-data-solr.

What I would like is something like this:

```
public interface FooRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<Foo, Long> {
    @Query(value = "name:?0")
    @Facet(json="{More complex facet JSON here}")
    FacetPage<Foo> findByNameAndFacet(String name, Pageable page);
}
```

Even then, I don't think the facets that come back would fit nicely into the `FacetPage` object.

What's the best way to handle this in an application that already has spring-data-solr?  My current option is to just use SolrClient seperatly from my spring-data-solr repositories.

PS - The reason why I'm interested in doing `json.facet` is for both aggregate functions `avg` and field/ranges with `domain` that exclude tags similar to http://yonik.com/multi-select-faceting/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can manage with field facets, to exclude a tagged filter, you could do something like:

`public interface FooRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<Foo, Long> {
    @Query(value = "name:?0", filters = { "{!tag=COLOR}color:?1" })
    @Facet(fields = { "{!ex=COLOR key=colors}color" })
    FacetPage<Foo> findByNameAndColorFacet(String name, String color, Pageable page);
}`